# my login page is not working, it just refreshes

Tags: php

i have a login and a registration system, the registration is working fine, and a hashed password is stored after finishing the registration, but when i log in, nothing happens, i don't get redirected if the login is successful, and my error messages don't appear if it's not successful, it just refreshes to the same login page.

i have three pages for the login system.

the login page that has the html form and so, and a sessions that appear if they're set (the error messeges)

```
 <form action="loginHandler.php" method="POST">
                     <h1>Log in </h1>
                     <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER" class="formtexts"><br>
                    <?php if(isset($_SESSION["h"])){ echo nl2br("$_SESSION[h]\r\n" ); unset($_SESSION["h"]); } ?>
                     <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" class="formtexts"> <br>
                     <?php if(isset($_SESSION["g"])){ echo nl2br("$_SESSION[g]\r\n" ); unset($_SESSION["g"]); } ?>
                     <a href="forgotpass.html" id="forgotpassword"> Forgot password?</a> <br>
                     <button type="submit" name ="finishlog" id="loginbutton">Log in</button> <br>

              </form>
```

the login handler page that deals with the page basically and redirects to another page if everything went good and the validation was successful.

```
if(isset($_POST['finishlog']))
{
    if (!empty('phone') && !empty('password'))
    {
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        
         $obj = new loginValidation();
         $obj->validateLogin($db, $phone, $password);
         
         if(isset($_SESSION["h"])==false && isset($_SESSION["g"])==false)
         {
              header("Location: first.php");
         }
         
    }
}
```

and the validation page that checks the password

```
function validateLogin($db,$phone,$password)
{
    
    
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT password FROM reg WHERE phone = :phone ");
    $stmt->bindParam(':phone',$phone);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        
    if($row > 0)
    {     
        unset($_SESSION["h"]); 
        
        if( password_verify($password,$row)==false)
        {
            $_SESSION["g"]=" password is not correct, please check and try again";
            header("Location: loginPage.php");
        }  
        else
            unset($_SESSION["g"]);  
             
    }
    
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["h"]=" phone number is not registered, please check and try again";
        header("Location: loginPage.php");
    }
    
}
```

i don't know what am missing, what is wrong?

Comment: Is it a typo? isn't it supposed to be if(!empty($_POST['phone']) && !empty($_POST['password']) ) ?

Comment: im not sure if (!empty($_POST['phone']) && !empty($_POST['password']) is the best way or not but i did the if (!empty('phone') && !empty('password')) on my registration system and it worked just fine, so i don't think this is the problem

Comment: `did the if (!empty('phone') && !empty('password')) on my registration system and it worked just fine, `....seems unlikely to be honest. You're just testing for literal strings, these are not useful tests, they don't validate the actual input.

Comment: `if($row > 0)` doesn't make much sense either. $row is a misnomer, it will actually contain the hashed password (or false if no row was found) so comparing it to a number is a bit weird. Try `if($row !== false)` instead.

Comment: But mainly what's missing from your question appears to be any attempt to do any basic debugging and narrow down the issue. Hence why you're getting semi-speculative comments instead of actual help - you haven't given us anything concrete to go on. we can't run your code or debug it, that's your task to do before asking a question.

Comment: @ZN1997 Please add `var_dump(...);` calls to your code for debugging purposes to check the content of the variables. You might want to run `var_dump($row);` and `var_dump($password);`. You should also check the return value of `$stmt->execute()` to see if it was successful or not.